# Escaping comma in com.Ostermiller.util.ExcelCSVPrinter.ExcelCSVPrinter

Tags: java, escaping

Im using this API Library 
[Ostermiller.org](https://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html). To be able to export a csv file from string.

```
ExcelCSVPrinter csvPrinter = new ExcelCSVPrinter(fileOutputStream);
csvPrinter.changeDelimiter('|');
csvPrinter.writeln(csvContent);
csvPrinter.flush();
csvPrinter.close();
```

The problem is when I write a sentence with a comma(,) inside it, it is treated as new column, which also states here [writeln()](https://ostermiller.org/utils/doc/com/Ostermiller/util/ExcelCSVPrinter.html#writeln(java.lang.String[])).

My question is, how am I able to escape the comma(,) to be able to write the data in one cell?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, im able to do a work around, but it does the job.
I iterate through my array, and manually appending each every line.

```
StringBuffer sb = null;
for(String[] a : csvContent) {
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(String b : a) {
        sb.append(b.trim());
        sb.append("|");
    }
    csvPrinter.writeln(sb.toString());
}
```